# Optimizing Response Filtering in Symfony API for Default Values (e.g., isActive)

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

Seeking guidance on optimizing response filtering in Symfony with a focus on implementing default values, like setting isActive to true. Despite efforts, my current solutions suffer from sub-optimal performance. I've utilized controllers, but data retrieval is time-consuming, requiring normalizers for response generation. I'm looking for insights into more efficient strategies or code patterns to speed up response rendering.

Here's an example scenario:

```
namespace App\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\AbstractNormalizer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\SerializerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use App\Entity\MasterList;

class MasterListController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/api/master_lists", name="get_active_master_lists", methods={"GET"})
     */
    public function getActiveMasterLists(SerializerInterface $serializer)
    {
        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(MasterList::class);

        // Use custom repository method to retrieve only active MasterLists
        $activeMasterLists = $repository->findActiveMasterLists();

        // Use Symfony Serializer to convert entities to array
        $serializedMasterLists = $serializer->normalize($activeMasterLists, null, [AbstractNormalizer::IGNORED_ATTRIBUTES => ['masterList']]);

        // Return the serialized data as a JSON response
        return new JsonResponse($serializedMasterLists);
    }
}
```

The current response time is 5000MS, which is high for the data volume. I've implemented pagination, indexed the isActive column, and tried caching. The client prefers a single response to avoid looping through multiple pages. How would you approach this differently for improved performance?

Comment: How many row did you return ? If this endpoint is an API why not fetching data by chunk in frontend, like an infinite pagination ?

Comment: tbh, don't know how you're caching and what the **actual requirements** are. A response time of 5s doesn't sound bad per se, depending on the amount of data. What you probably won't get is *all* of the following: 1. quick response time, 2. massive amounts of data (i.e. no paging) 3. uncached data (i.e. most accurate and "fresh" data) 4. super simple code. One or more of these someone has to compromise on. for example, turning objects - which you have just created from serialized form (ORM did this for you) - into serialized form to never be used again as objects, sounds exceedingly wasteful.

Answer (score -1):

I decided to move the whole operation to the database. I created a view at database level where i set the filters. This has considerably improved the speed of receiving a response.